# Unity 5: How to rotate an object in 3d space relative to camera axes

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to write a very simple 3d model viewer that allows the user to click and drag on the x and y axes to rotate an object. The problem I am facing with my included code sample is that, when I rotate something, say, about the y axis, and then try to rotate about the x axis, I find that the object is rotated about the **object's** x axis instead of the x-axis from the perspective of the camera.

I'm effectively trying to simulate rotating something along the z-axis, albeit through two motions.

```
public Transform obj;

private Vector3 screenPoint;
private Vector3 offset;

//public float minX = 270.0f;
//public float maxX = 360.0f;

//public float minY = -90.0f;
//public float maxY = 90.0f;

public float sensX = 100.0f;
public float sensY = 100.0f;

float rotationY = 0.0f;
float rotationX = 0.0f;

float posX = 0.0f;
float posY = 0.0f;

void Update() {

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
        rotationX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensX * Time.deltaTime;
        //rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(rotationX, minX, maxX);

        rotationY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensY * Time.deltaTime;
        //rotationY = Mathf.Clamp(rotationY, minY, maxY);

        Quaternion q = Quaternion.Euler(rotationY, -rotationX, 0);
        transform.rotation = q;
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(1)) {
        posX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * 25.0f * Time.deltaTime;
        posY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * 25.0f * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = new Vector3(posX, posY, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to rotate around the z-axis, you could try the [`transform.RotateAround`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html) function.  This will allow you to specify a point (as a `Vector3`), a rotation axis (again as a `Vector3`), and a degree to which to rotate.  This function can modify both the `position` and the `rotation` elements of your transform.